# Select Rows in a uniform order

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by, rows

I have a table customer and 100 rows in it. a status column is set for active/inactive customer in the table.

What i want to do is to select all customers from the table in a specific order 
ie

first 7 active customers then 3 inactive customers again 7 active customers  and 3 inactive and so on

How can I achieve this in a query.

I am using sql server 2008 . Please Help me....

Comment: Do you have another column, in addition to the status column, that lets you easily distinguish between the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it, based on the minimal requirements you've listed so far:

```
;with NumberedRows as (
    select
        *, --TODO - pick columns
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY status ORDER BY PKID) - 1 as rn
    from
        table
), AlteredOrdering as (
    select
        *, --TODO - pick columns
        CASE
            WHEN status = 'active' THEN (10 * (rn/7)) + (rn % 7)
            WHEN status = 'inactive' THEN (10 * (rn/3)) + 7 + (rn % 3)
        END as FinalOrder
    from NumberedRows
)
select * from AlteredOrdering ORDER BY FinalOrder
```

Obviously, altering the table and column names as appropriate. `PKID` is assumed to be some other column in the table against which the individual rows can be ordered.

---

The magic numbers in the AlteredOrdering CTE are hopefully obvious - 7 and 3 come from the question, and represent how many of each item should appear in each "group". The 10 is the total size of each "group". So if it was 9 active, 4 inactive, the CASE expression would look like:

```
WHEN status = 'active' THEN (13 * (rn/9)) + (rn % 9)
WHEN status = 'inactive' THEN (13 * (rn/4)) + 9 + (rn % 4)
```

Comment: +1 for the math. Well done, sir. I tested it on a large dataset here, just out of curiosity. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you cannot. It would likely require processing of the data once you had retrieved it from SQL

Answer (score 0):

if you have only 100 rows then perhaps limit x,y combine with union can help

```
select * from table where status=active limit 0,7
union
select * from table where status=inactive limit 7,3
union
select * from table where status=active limit 10,7
union
select * from table where status=inactive limit 17,3
...
```

Comment: thanks for yous for your answer.   eg I told like 100 actually there may thousands of rows in the table